# Displaying inheritance on ER Diagrams?

Tags: entity-relationship, erd

In my Spring Boot app, I have an entity relationship diagram as shown below and looking for a proper way for displaying inheritance on it. I have a look at dozens of pages, but could not find any example (most of them use different kind of diagrams).

[image: er_diagram]

Normally I use the annotations to show one-to-many- etc. relationships as shown between student-course and course-professor. But I am not sure it the arrows filled and empty is a proper way to display inheritance between User - Student and User - Professor.

How should I display inheritance properly for an ER Diagram (not class, etc.)?

Comment: You have tagged your question with the UML tag and with the class-diagram tag. Could you please explain why? You have an ER diagram with crow's foot notation, which is not compatible with UML or class diagrams.

Comment: You could, for instance, have applied the UML tag to indicate that you were looking for a solution in terms of UML. You do not explicitly mention that in your question and that is why am in doubt of your need. Please have patience with me, if I do not understand you correctly. I'm trying to help.

Comment: I have upvoted the question because it shows research effort, it shows an attempt to solve it, with a clear image and it addresses only one specific issue other community members might also run into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ER modeling technique typically does not include any inheritance feature. There are several ways to extend the technique, but there is no single way how you *should* model inheritance.

UML is a popular modeling language, which does not have the crow's foot notation as used in your example, but it does have an inheritance symbol. If you want to borrow that: it is like the arrow you have drawn between User and Student: an arrow with an empty triangle at the end, pointing from the special entity to the more general entity.

Comment: Thanks a lot, voted up. Actually it would be an ER Diagram or Domain Model, but don't want to draw as a Class Diagram. For this reason, is the arror (empty triangle) between User and the Student is ok to show inheritance? Or would you suggest a similar diagram and update this according to that diagram?

Comment: If you don't have to adhere to some standard modeling technique, it is ok. Explain to your audience what you are doing. Personally, I use the crow's foot notation without inheritance for relational database modeling and UML for most other purposes. Please mark my answer as accepted if you are satisfied. It gives me more credit points :-)

Comment: I think this one that I am using is also "crow's foot notation", right? On the other hand can we also call this a "Domain Model" besides ER Diagram?

Comment: @devx you can call it how you like, but "domain model" might be confusing, because also used with UML for modelling real domains, i.e. not only the structural data view, but also the behavior. A better name would be "Database implementation model".   There is no extension of "Crow's foot" notation for inheritance as far as I know (the different Ehanced ERD (EERD) notations are based on Chen's notation (the one with the boxes for the entities, the large diamonds for the relations, and the bubbles for the attributes.

Comment: @Christophe What about **Domain Design** ?

Comment: "Domain" usually refers to the real world. A domain model is a model of the real world. Every entity and every attribute shown in the domain model shall also exist in the real world, not only in the database. In that case you can call it a domain model.

Answer (score 0):

I would label the entities like user:student and user:professor